# <script async="">先で、document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load, false);するとうまくいかない

Tags: javascript

**下記で、asyncを削除するとうまくいくのですが、そのままだとノーリアクションです**
・何故でしょうか？
・「非同期でHTML解釈終了時に呼び出されるイベント」という考え方がおかしいのでしょうか？
・仮にasyncを残すとしたら、「document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"」は不要でしょうか？
・両者の違い(使い分け方)が良く分かりません

---

```
<script async="" src="hoge.js"></script>
```

hoge.js

```
function test() { 
  var el = document.getElementById("piyo"); 
  el.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
    console.log(this);
  }, false);
} 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", test, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` は、「スクリプトのロードで本体HTMLのパーズをブロックしない」「スクリプトのロードが終わったら実行される」という挙動です。スクリプト実行時にHTMLのパーズは終わっているかもしれませんし、終わっていないかもしれません。このコードで`async`を使いたいのでしたら、「`document.readyState`が `"loading"` の場合は `DOMContentLoaded` に `test` を登録、それ以外は `test` を即実行。」となるでしょう。

欲しい挙動は `async` ではなく `defer` ではないでしょうか。

Comment: deferが分からないのですが、挙動的には「window.onload」と「jQueryの$(document).ready」の何れに近いのでしょうか？ 何れもHTMLパーズ終了後に実行される？ 画像読込は待つのでしょうか？

Comment: わからない場合は規格を読むといいです。https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-defer 。defer は ready 相当です。画像などサブリソースは待ちません。

Comment: リンク提示ありがとうございました。こんな分かりやすい図が掲載されていたのですね。参考になりました